Cannot Suspend Due to USB Errors After Shorting USB Port
I recently shorted one of the USB ports on my laptop (ThinkPad X1 Extreme 2nd Gen, running Ubuntu 24.04.1). Since then, I have been unable to suspend my system normally. Attempting to suspend results in the screen briefly turning off, followed by being returned to the lock screen.
Here are the relevant logs from journalctl during the suspend attempt:
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: usb usb1: PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: usb usb1: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: usb usb2: PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: usb usb2: PM: failed to suspend async: error -16
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: random: crng reseeded on system resumption
Nov 26 23:12:46 finn-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd kernel: PM: suspend exit

I have attempted to try to disable or force ignore the broken port (1-1) but it does not have any effect on the result.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
